# GraphQL Timestamp Difference in Query

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, graphql-java, prisma-graphql, typegraphql

I have one issue where I am trying to get the difference in the timestamp from the 2 existing fields from the schema but getting issues which says Error: Invalid number, expected digit but got: "U". I am trying to convert below sql query part into graphql query.

```
ROUND(avg(timestampdiff(SECOND, JobStartDateTime, UpdateDateTime)),0) as AvgTime
```

And once we get the difference can we parse it to valid type of data like datetime? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

```
query MyQuery {
  MyQuery {
    Region
    JobStartDateTime
    UpdateDateTime
    JobStartDateTime-UpUpdateDateTime
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add more details of your setup. What does your resolver look like?

Comment: @Roy Below is the the model and there are some aggregations which we support to get the details from the tablelike findManyCount, findManyRecords etc and querying through graphql is supported for the same. 

model MyQuery {
  JobId             BigInt    id default(autoincrement())
  QueueDateTime     DateTime  db.DateTime(6)
  JobStartDateTime  DateTime? db.DateTime(0)
  UpdateDateTime    DateTime? db.DateTime(6)
  Error             String?   db.LongText
  ExceptionType     String?   db.VarChar(100)
}

Comment: 1) You can't do math in a GraphQL query - `JobStartDateTime-UpdateDateTime` will syntax error. 2) A time difference in seconds can't usefully be converted to a datetime.